# AMP: The mandatory tag 'html ⚡ for top-level html' is missing or incorrect

Tags: amp-html

I am getting the following error from Google Webmaster Tools for AMP:

> The mandatory tag 'html ⚡ for top-level html' is missing or incorrect.

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Sample code or link to a sample page?

Comment: This page is showing five errors on Google Webmaster Tools. When you run the validator it shows those errors for the first second then they go away... What's up with that? http://www.dodgecountyfairgrounds.com/2015/04/23/flea-market-and-craft-fair-dates-announced/amp/

Answer (score 3):

Replace where you have `<html>` to `<html amp>` or `<html ⚡>`

Comment: how should I change html tag in my wordpress website?

Answer (score 2):

Based on the document - [AMP Validation Errors](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/validation_errors)

> Valid AMP documents must not inlude any validation errors. The purpose of this document is to help you better understand and fix any validation errors you encounter when you [*validate your AMP pages*](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/guides/validate.html). For a complete overview of the validation errors, see the [*AMP validator specification*](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/master/validator/validator-main.protoascii).

#### Mandatory tag missing

[image]

The following tags must be present in all AMP docs:

[image]

These mandatory tags include a **`mandatory: true`** field in the [AMP validator spec](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/master/validator/validator-main.protoascii); they are also referenced in the [AMP specification](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/spec.html).

Hope this helps.